# Expresso Store not adding products & no exp_store_carts table

Tags: expresso-store

I'm running Store 2.5.1 and EE 2.10.1. (Building locally.)

The `{exp:store:cart}` isn't displaying anything and the system doesn't seem to be adding products to the cart. The `{exp:store:checkout}` also turns up blank.

Also, there's no `exp_store_carts` table in my DB.

Not sure what could be causing this or how to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working. Had to save settings to ensure that the cart would work. That, and had to correct a bit of code on the cart/checkout page to get it working right.

Answer (score 1):

If the carts table is missing from your install I would uninstall Store and reinstall Store. You should also be able to open up (if I am remember correctly) `third_party/store/config/scheme.php` to get the columns name/type/length/default values for the cart table and add it manually.

Comment: Weird. I uninstall and reinstalled and the table didn't get created. Did that twice. Then I opened up ../store/config/schema.sql and did a find for exp_store_carts but nothing is there. This is from a fresh download of Store 2.5.1.